# Find all those hosts which has encountered "bios error" due to upgrade on any day. Can use any Database like MySQL/ Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Find all those hosts which has encountered "bios error" due to upgrade on any day. Can use any Database like MySQL/ Oracle

```
----
Log
-----
date       time hostname message
2019-07-02 8:00 abc      upgrade done
2019-07-02 8:00 abc      upgrade done
2019-07-02 8:05 abc      tester run
2019-07-02 8:10 abc      bios error
2019-07-02 8:11 abc      upgrade done
2019-07-02 8:15 abc      tester run
2019-07-02 8:20 abc      bios error
2019-07-02 7:00 xyz      bios error
2019-07-02 8:10 host5    bios error
2019-07-02 8:20 host5    upgrade done
2019-07-02 6:00 host2    upgrade done
2019-07-04 5:00 host3    upgrade done
2019-07-03 5:05 host4    upgrade done
```

Comment: Doesn't `WHERE` do what you want?

Comment: What does "due to upgrade on any day" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `LOG` is a table with at least a column named `MESSAGE` you can use the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM LOG
  WHERE MESSAGE = 'bios error'
```